# How to merge/align two different times of data into one data per one single time?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, I have two tables of data per different times below.

```
Table 1                       Table2
Time            Value         Time            Type
8/1/2018 10:30  3.5           8/1/2018 10:20    A
8/1/2018 11:30  4.3           8/1/2018 11:15    C
8/1/2018 12:30  5.1           8/1/2018 13:00    D 
8/1/2018 13:30  2.7
```

And I would like merge and align like below:

```
Time            Value    Type   
8/1/2018 10:30  3.5       A  
8/1/2018 11:30  4.3       C   
8/1/2018 12:30  5.1       C     
8/1/2018 13:30  2.7       D
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,F:G,2,TRUE)
```

This will require that the values in table 2 be sorted on the time to work.

[image]